# Reading data from a file and storing it into a structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm a beginner to C++ and I'm having trouble reading blocks of data from an input file and displaying that data properly in an output file. The text inside the input file I need to use looks like this:

&  Warehouse   ÿÿÿÿ    X¦a¤  Ãq¹B

The output should look something like this:

Id: (some integer)

Department: Warehouse

Hours: (some float)

Heres what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#<include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct employee {
   int id;
   char department[25];
   float hours;
};

int main()
{
   ifstream inputFile;
   ofstream outputFile;
   string inFilename, outFileName;

   cout << "Please give me two file names" << endl;
   getline(cin, inFileName);
   getline(cin, outFileName);


   inputFile.open(inFileName);
   outputFile.open(outFileName);

   if (inputFile.eof())
   {
      inputFile.close();
      outputFile.close();
   }
   string buffer;
   employee emp;
   inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp));
   while (!inputFile.eof())
   {

      outputFile << "Id:\t" << emp.id << endl;
      outputFile << "Department:\t" << emp.department << endl;
      outputFile << "Hours:\t" << emp.hours << endl;
      inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp));
   }

   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

Id: 538968358

Department: Warehouse   ÿÿÿÿ    X¦a¤  Ãq¹BÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ î

Hours:  92.7222

Why is it still outputting these strange characters on the department line?
Im having a hard time understanding what exactly the read function is doing when I call it and I think this might be whats causing the issue. I've looked into what the read function does but I couldn't find anything that could explain what was happening in this context specifically with the reinterpret cast. I know it takes two parameters, the first one being "char*" but in this case we are using the reinterpret cast to take the characters and turn them into type employee defined by the structure. The second parameter is sizeof and thats supposed to indicate how many characters its reading from the file I think? If I knew exactly how the read() function was working in this context I could probably figure out why its outputting the strange characters.

Comment: The `department` member variable has room for 25 char, so the `read` command fills it up. If you want a more nuanced reading, like reading up to a space (' '), you must write more nuanced code. I would suggest avoiding strings (`char[]`) and sticking to simple types like `int` and `double` until you have a good grip on binary I/O problems.

Comment: **"The text inside the input file"** -- is it even a text file, or is it binary. The `ÿÿÿÿ X¦a¤ Ãq¹B` does not look like normal text.

Comment: It is a .info file

Comment: I suspect it is binary. Were you given the number of bytes you were to read, or the format of the file for you to craft an input routine to read the file? You have to know what is in a binary file to know how to read it. (e.g. 1st 8-bytes `double`, next 4-bytes `int`, etc..) Is it just supposed to be full of `struct employee` or does it have an `int` up front telling you how many there are. Also recall, if the `.info` file was not written on windoze, then there is no guarantee you can read it due to differences in padding of struct between compilers.

Comment: Post a link to your `.info` file, or if it is just a hundred bytes or so, post a hexdump of it.

Comment: https://uwyo.instructure.com/courses/504021/files/43170364/download?verifier=SGc0hwQWjtbtEQl6HM0qeM1TTVkpTeCqqBA5MpDa&wrap=1

Comment: There is the file I used in the example above we were also given several other files to use, the others containing more data. Here is one of the others: https://uwyo.instructure.com/courses/504021/files/43170366/download?verifier=SxI5VJsArOy7v8dcUKnNNOKEmvM0PYyp9vao0qtX&wrap=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually fairly close. Your primary stumbling block comes from failing to open `inputFile` in binary mode (e.g. specifying `mode` as `ios::binary`). Your secondary issues have to do with validation. All input must be validated (especially user input). All file openings must be validated (and you should validate a close after a write. by checking if `failbit` indicates a stream error following close. *note* this is only necessary after a *write*)

Putting those pieces together (and leaving the check of `failbit` after close of `outputFile` to you), it looks like you intended something similar to the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct employee {
    int id;
    char department[25];
    float hours;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    string inFilename, outFilename, buffer;
    struct employee emp;

    cout << "Please give me two file names" << endl;
    /* validate all input succeeds */
    if (!getline (cin, inFilename)) {
        cerr << "error: invalid input for input file.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (!getline (cin, outFilename)) {
        cerr << "error: invalid input for output file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* open file in binary mode 'ios::binary' */
    inputFile.open (inFilename, ios::binary);

    /* valdiate all files open for reading/writing */
    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        perror (("error opening: " + inFilename).c_str());
        return 1;
    }
    outputFile.open (outFilename);
    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        perror (("error opening: " + outFilename).c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    /* while each read succeeds, write to output file */
    while (inputFile.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp)))
    {
        outputFile << "Id:\t" << emp.id << endl;
        outputFile << "Department:\t" << emp.department << endl;
        outputFile << "Hours:\t" << emp.hours << endl;
    }

    inputFile.close();  /* close files */
    outputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Example output data1.info**

```
$ ./bin/read_binary_info
Please give me two file names
dat/data1.info
dat/data1.txt

$ cat dat/data1.txt
Id:     579
Department:     Warehouse
Hours:  95.9083
Id:     23
Department:     Admin
Hours:  33.7954
Id:     901
Department:     Operations
Hours:  99.5081
Id:     193
Department:     Admin
Hours:  2.15763
...
Id:     707
Department:     Maintenance
Hours:  63.801
Id:     110
Department:     Sales
Hours:  1.22974
```

**Example outoput data3.info**

```
$ ./bin/read_binary_info
Please give me two file names
dat/data3.info
dat/data3.txt

$ cat dat/data3.txt
Id:     294
Department:     Warehouse
Hours:  92.7222
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Made the validation changes and opened the input file as a binary but I'm still getting the weird characters in my output. Does it matter where I have the files saved?

Comment: It shouldn't, but it could matter how you saved it. I just went to your links and hit "save". No application in between (except for the browser to get there). Note how I changed your read-loop (the `while`) to eliminate the internal `.feof` and the read at the end. While that should only effect your last struct (if at all), that shouldn't be the cause of your problem. Do you know if the `.info` files were originally created on a Linux machine with `gcc` instead of VS? That can make a difference in the internal struct *padding* as I mentioned in my comment to your question.

Comment: I have compiled on VS 10 on Win7 (32-bit) and both files read fine, so padding seems to be a non-issue. VS 10 and gcc are treating the padding the same. (if it is 4-byte aligned, it would  be 36-bytes per employee, if 8-byte aligned it would be 40-bytes per employee. I'll do a quick check, but

Comment: I've checked. On both 64-bit Linux and 32-bit Win7, I get `sizeof emp` as `36-bytes`. I'll boot 64-bit win 10 and give it a try. If you have tried with the code I posted, padding is the only thing that would make the difference.

Comment: @Will-i-am I have now confirmed on VS 2017 (both 32-bit and 64-bit builds) that the data files read fine. (I would have been done sooner, but just like any windoze that hasn't booted in a couple of week it has to spend 10 minutes updating itself before it settles down to being usable....)

Answer (score 0):

In c++ the char[] must include a \0 charater for indicate the end of the text.
otherwise unspected resuts because qye data of the array is not initialized to any values and contains arbitrary characters.
When you try to output the char[25] departament, if after 'warehouse' dont have a \0 char then output all 25 chars.